# Vi: changing tabs to comma in last n columns of a file

Tags: regex, vi, substitution

I have a file that is separated by tabs and on each line the amount of columns is 9. The last column exists out of another tab separated list. I have to replace the tabs in the last column with a space+comma. This needs to happen in the Vi editor.

```
example
C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9
.. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. foo1 foo2 foo3
.. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. foo4
.. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. foo5 foo6

results in

example
C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9
.. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. foo1,foo2,foo3
.. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. foo4
.. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. foo5,foo6
```

I have already tried this command:

```
:s/^[^#]([^\t]*\t)\{8\}\(\([^\t]*\)\(\t\)\)*/\1 \3 ,/
```

but this gives an error.
The [^#] is to avoid the command changing the files starting with #.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to do this in a single command, but it seems there is no way to replace all but the first eight occurrences of a pattern on the same line in VI/VIM.

I did find a way to do what you want, but it takes 10 consecutive commands.

```
:v/^#/ s/\t/<TAB>/
:v/^#/ s/\t/<TAB>/
:v/^#/ s/\t/<TAB>/
:v/^#/ s/\t/<TAB>/
:v/^#/ s/\t/<TAB>/
:v/^#/ s/\t/<TAB>/
:v/^#/ s/\t/<TAB>/
:v/^#/ s/\t/<TAB>/
:v/^#/ s/\t/,/g
:v/^#/ s/<TAB>/\t/g
```

Feel free to replace `<TAB>` by any other placeholder that is obscure enough to be unlikely to occur in the file under edit.

**EDIT:** you can combine the 10 commands into a single big one-liner:

```
:v/^#/ s/\t/<TAB>/|s/\t/<TAB>/|s/\t/<TAB>/|s/\t/<TAB>/|s/\t/<TAB>/|s/\t/<TAB>/|s/\t/<TAB>/|s/\t/<TAB>/|s/\t/,/g|s/<TAB>/\t/g
```

Answer (score 0):

In VIM, it *is* possible with a single substitution. May not work in VI.

```
:let @a=0 | v/^#/ s/\t\|$/\=setreg('a', len(submatch(0)) ? @a+1 : 0) || @a > 8 ? ',' : submatch(0)/g
```

Explanation:

- `let @a=0` : fill register `a` with value 0
- `v/^#/` : lines starting with a `#` are not affected
- `s/\t\|$/.../g` : replace every tab; make an additional replacement at end of line
- `\=` : the replacement string is calculated by an expression
- `setreg('a', ...)` : fill register `a` with a new value
- `len(submatch(0))` : non-zero for every tab; zero at end of line
- `... ? @a+1 : 0` : register `a` is incremented for every tab, and reset to zero at end of line
- `||` : `setreg` always returns zero; `||` effectively discards this return value
- `@a > 8` : true from the 9th tab on
- `? ','` : replace those tabs with comma
- `: submatch(0)` : replace neither the first 8 tabs, nor the end of line anchor

Inspired by: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Making_a_list_of_numbers